'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command
I had installed django at C:\Users\05554F744
Now, to create a Django project, I'm doing C:\Users\05554F744\Box\Nupur\Learning\Python\Django>django -admin startproject djangoprojects
I get the message "'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."
What should I do to fix this? I want my "djangoprojects" folder inside C:\Users\05554F744\Box\Nupur\Learning\Python\Django

Remove the space from django-admin.

-admin is not a flag, the name of the command is django-admin so in full as one word:
django-admin startproject djangoprojects
In fact it is a short version of python -m django, so we can use:
python -m django startproject djangoprojects
